# how to fetch records from parameter file

Tags: plsql

Hi I would like to know how I can fetch the records when I'm using parameter file.
My scripts is like that. when I execute it, I got error message. Please help me to fix this script.

Thank you in advance

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testappt
  (
   XFILE IN VARCHAR2
   ) is

   xfpt varchar2(1):='F';

   TYPE curtype IS REF CURSOR;
   appt_cur   curtype;
   appt_rec  appt_cur%ROWTYPE; -- error

BEGIN

  open appt_cur for  'SELECT * FROM ' || xfile || ' where fpt!= :xfpt ' using xfpt;
  loop

      fetch appt_cur into appt_rec  -- error
      exit when appt_cur%not found; -- error

    execute immediate  'update ' || xfile || ' set apptgrp=46' || 'where reptrc=6269' ||     
   'and og=trim(0||6)' || 'and trim(a_jc)=2876';
    commit;

  end loop;     
end testappt;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need some spaces in your literals.  Try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testappt
  (
   XFILE IN VARCHAR2
   ) is

   xfpt varchar2(1):='F';

   TYPE curtype IS REF CURSOR;
   appt_cur   curtype;
   appt_rec  appt_cur%ROWTYPE; -- error

BEGIN

  open appt_cur for  'SELECT * FROM ' || xfile || ' where fpt!= :xfpt ' using xfpt;
  loop

      fetch appt_cur into appt_rec  -- error
      exit when appt_cur%not found; -- error

    execute immediate  'update ' || xfile ||
                        ' set apptgrp=46' ||
                        ' where reptrc=6269' ||     
                        ' and og=trim(0||6)' ||
                        ' and trim(a_jc)=2876';
    commit;

  end loop;     
end testappt;
/
```

Share and enjoy.